# Select field conditionally from mysql

Tags: mysql, case

Is it possible to use `Select` with `Case` to select from one of several fields depending on which of them is null or not?

I basically want to return a value for all records with logic that says

```
Return $Value from FIeldA if not null 
else from FieldB if not NULL 
else from FieldC if not Null 
else '0'
```

I've used Case/When/Then to compare values from a specific field but not as a way of comparing values between fields and not sure if this is possible.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer,** use [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT COALESCE(FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, 0) AS FieldName
FROM tableName;
```

It will give you the first non nullable value from the three fields `FieldA, FieldB, FieldC`. If all are null, then it will return 0. Which what you are trying to do.

**Long answer,** use `CASE` expression.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check multiple filed and if null then return same result 0 then use `COALESCE` function . this is simple code

```
SELECT COALESCE(filed1, filed2, filed3, 0) as output from table;
```

for more information
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp

extra option if you want to select filed using condition then use case. this is demo code

```
SELECT CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN 'this is case one'
WHEN 2 THEN 'this is case two' 
ELSE 'this is not in the case'
END as 'how to execute case statement';
```

for more information

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/